# Polymorphism - exercise

Tags: c#

Alright, so this is the exercise:

> Define a class named student,
>   containing three grades of students.
>   The class will have a function that
>   calculates the grades average. Now,
>   define a class named student1 which
>   will be derived from student and will
>   add a function to calculate the sum of
>   the grades.In the Main program, define
>   a student variable and object of type
>   student1. Perform placement of the
>   object to variable and run the
>   function of student1.

Note: This is not homework, I'm learning this my own.
This is the code:

```
class Student
{
    protected int grade1, grade2, grade3;
    public Student(int grade1, int grade2, int grade3)
    {
        this.grade1 = grade1;
        this.grade2 = grade2;
        this.grade3 = grade3;
    }
    public double Average()
    {
        return (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    }
}
class Student1 : Student
{
    public Student1(int grade1, int grade2, int grade3)
        : base(grade1, grade2, grade3)
    {
    }
    public double Sum()
    {
        return grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

I don't really know what to do in the main class, how do I perform this placement and also, I wanted to know what's the benefit of doing it, let me know if I have mistakes so far, thanks alot.

Comment: don't really know what to do in the main class, how do I perform this placement and also, I wanted to know what's the benefit of doing it, let me know if I have mistakes so far, thanks alot.

Comment: Have you run this through a compiler yet?  Did it complain about Student.Average()?

Comment: Guys where's this part in the question? : In the Main program, define a student variable and object of type student1. Perform placement of the object to variable and run the function of student1.

Comment: It's all good so far but they asked me to perform placement from object to variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK: I guess this is what they're looking for, although the english is a little ropey:

1) Declare student variable

```
 Student s;
```

2) Declare Student1 object

```
 Student1 s1 = new Student1(1,2,3);
```

3) Perform placement of object to variable:

```
s = s1;
```

4) Run the function (Note you'll have to cast s to Student1 type to access the Type specific function Sum)

```
Console.WriteLine(((Student1)s).Sum());
```

Comment: Exactly, can you tell me please what's the point of doing this performance : placement of object to variable?

Comment: Btw can you tell me what I had to do if they wouldv'e told me  to perform placement of variable to object?

Comment: I don't see the point of this exercise one little bit - this isn't a good example of Object Orientated Design - my advice would be to get a better book!

Answer (score 1):

Following exactly what was described by the exercise:

```
// Define a student variable.
Student s;

// And object of type Student1.
Student1 s1 = new Student1(10, 5, 8);

// Perform placement of the object to variable.
s = s1;

// And run the function of Student1.
// But it makes no sense...
s1.Sum();

// Maybe the exercise wants it:
((Student1)s).Sum();

// Which makes no sense too, since is making an idiot cast.
// But for learning purposes, ok.
```

Well, I don't believe this exercise is taking any advantage of [polymorphism in C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#C.23). I suggest you reading the link to see a real usage sample.

Comment: They asked for this: , define a student variable and object of type student1. Perform placement of the object to variable and run the function of student1.

Comment: I am afraid your answer doesn't seem to do what is asked for.

Comment: @ErickPetru Oh, I understand, but can you tell me what's the benefit of performing this replacement?

Comment: Edited following the sentence: "In the Main program, define a Student variable and object of type Student1. Perform placement of the object to variable and run the function of Student1".

Comment: Edited again explaining the code and suggesting more reading.

Answer (score 1):

The primary flaw I see in your code from an OOP perspective is making Student1 extend from Student.  When using inheritance, make sure it's a true extension (is a).  You would be better served by making 1 student class and implementing the Sum and Average methods.

I think the following would be sufficient from an OOP perspective.

```
class Student
{
    protected int grade1, grade2, grade3;

    public Student(int grade1, int grade2, int grade3)
    {
       this.grade1 = grade1;
       this.grade2 = grade2;
       this.grade3 = grade3;
    }

    public double Average()
    {
        return (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    }

    public double Sum()
    {
        return grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's trying to teach the basics of grammar, etc.  If you're new I would highly suggest, you take your time learning the principals of OOP especially inheritance vs. composition.  Good luck Rich!

Comment: I'm learning through the book, I learned already inheritance, any idea what to do please?

Comment: This answer in no way relates to the question asked - it's a specific problem, not a request for best advice on how to implement the functionality.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the original question.  I was thinking he was asking more by including "let me know if I have mistakes so far".  My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what it means.. although its really badly worded in my eyes.

*In the Main program, define a student variable and object of type student1. Perform placement of the object to variable and run the function of student1.*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //define a student variable and object of type student1.
    Student student = new Student1(100, 99, 98); 

    //Perform placement of the object to variable and run the function of student1
    var sum = ((Student1)student ).Sum();

}
```